# Is there a dockerfile RUN command that executes the argument on the host?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

We're trying to build a Docker stack that includes our complete application: a Postgres database and at least one web application.

When the stack is started, we expect the application to be immediately working - there should not be any delay due to database setup or data import. So the database schema (DDL) and the initial data have to be imported when the image is created.

This could be achieved by a `RUN` command in the dockerfile, for example

```
RUN psql.exe -f initalize.sql -h myhost -d mydatabase -U myuser
RUN data-import.exe myhost mydatabase myuser
```

However, AFAIU this would execute `data-import.exe` inside the Postgres container, which can only work if the Postgres container is a Windows container. Our production uses a Linux Postgres distribution, so this is not a good idea. We need the image to be a Linux Postgres container.

So the natural solution is to execute `data-import.exe` on the host, like this:

- When we run `docker build`, a Linux Postgres container is started.
- `RUN psql.exe ...` runs some SQL commands inside the Postgres container.
- Now, our `data-import.exe` is executed on the host. Its Postgres client connects to the database in the container and imports the data.
- When the data import is done, the data is committed to the image, and docker builds an image which contains the Postgres database together with the imported data.

Is there such a command? If not, how can we implement this scenario in docker?

Comment: This might be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740828/commit-data-in-a-mysql-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct tool, a dockerfile is not a hammer for everything.

Obviously you come from a state where you had postgres up before using some import-tool.  Now you can mimic that strategy by firing up a postgres container (without dockerfile, just docker/kubernetes). Then run the import-tool, stop the postgres-container, and make a snapshot of the result using "docker commit". The committed image will be used for the next stages of your deployment.

Answer (score 1):

In Docker generally the application data is stored *separately* from images and containers; for instance you'd frequently use a `docker run -v` option to store data in a host directory or Docker volume so that it would outlive its container.  You wouldn't generally try to bake data into an image, both for scale reasons and because any changes will be lost when a container exits.

As you've described the higher-level problem, I might distribute something like a "test kit" that included a `docker-compose.yml` and a base data directory.  Your Docker Compose file would use a stock PostgreSQL container with data:

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:10.5
  volumes:
    - './postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
```

To answer the specific question you asked, `docker build` steps *only* run individual commands within Docker container space; they can't run arbitrary host commands, read filesystem content outside of the tree containing the `Dockerfile`, or write any sort of host filesystem content outside the container.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the last sentence of your first paragraph: why does "baked-in" data affect scalability negatively? I'm not talking about huge amounts of data. And yes, if the data doesn't live in a volume, any changes would be lost. But this could be a desired scenario (for example if the container is the backend for a CI/CD process).